# Why does my React app fail to compile when checking for one undefined variable, but not the other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and am building a component locally. I would like this component to use data from my site when it is built and uploaded on there, but for building and testing it I just want it to use dummy data.

To do that I am checking if an object exists (is defined) or not. I have 2 of these checks - one passess fine, but the other causes a `not defined` error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: pageData is not defined`.

The two checks in my code are:

```
let greeting = '',
  productsOnPage = '';
function App() {

  if (typeof componentObj === "undefined") {
    greeting = 'Data not from object';
  }
  else {
    greeting = componentObj.title;  // eslint-disable-line
  }
  // ^ this works

  if (typeof pageData === "undefined") {
    productsOnPage = 'Dummy product';
  }
  else {
    productsOnPage = pageData.product;  // eslint-disable-line
  }
  // ^ this causes the error
```

The component compiles successfully without any errors or warnings. However, in the browser I get the `undefined` error.

I don't understand why one works and why one doesn't. Would anyone be able to steer me in the right direction with this?

Comment: where is componentObj and pageData coming from?

Comment: @epascarello they're global variables set on the website. They are used when I build the App and deploy it on the site. Of course, I don't have these objects availably locally which is why I'm using these conditionals

Comment: Well apparently it is not defined. It is not great practice to use window in a react app. I would check to see if it is actually being written to the page. If it is on window. You could check `window.pageData`